# Failed with exception Wrong FS error in Hive 0.11 in CDH5

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh

I tried to load a Hive table in S3 but I got the following error:

```
Failed with exception Wrong FS: s3n://.... expected: hdfs://
```

It looks like I can only use a local HDFS for this somehow? That's very inconvenience for me. My S3 credentials are set correctly (have Write permission to the S3 bucket I used). When I tried with HDFS (still reading from s3n from writing to HDFS), my query worked fine. Also I have a Pig script (0.12) reading from and writing to s3n, it is working fine.

I am using CDH5.4 and any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more.  how you set s3 filesystem?

Comment: Yes, reading from it isn't a problem and Pig script has been working fine (reading from and writing to S3).